# What is the meaning of $F_X(X)$?

Tags: probability-theory

I know that $F_X(x) = \text{Pr}(X \le x)$ for some random variable $X$ and its realization $x$, but what does $F_X(X)$ mean then? It wasn't specified further in the lecture, unfortunately. Furthermore, it was noted that $Pr(F_X(X) \le x) = x$ when $X$ is uniformly distributed, which I don't understand either.

Comment: This is the random variable $U=g(X)$ with $g=F_X$, that is, $U(\omega)=g(X(\omega))$ for every $\omega$ in $\Omega$. When $X$ is uniformly distributed on $(0,1)$, $F_X(x)=x$ for every $x$ in $(0,1)$ hence indeed, $F_X(X)=X$ (not "$=x$", which would be absurd). Is this your question?

Comment: I re-edited the question, copied the wrong stuff. Sorry!

Comment: Thus... no question left?

Comment: Sure, it's still there.

Comment: Which one is not answered in my comment? Please be specific.

Comment: It's still left to answer why  $Pr(F_X(X) \le x) = x$ holds, which was the part that I edited.

Comment: If $X$ is a continuous random variable, then $F_{X}(x)$ is a strictly increasing function. Therefore, $P(F_{X}(X) \leq x) = P(F^{-1}_{X}(F_{X}(X)) \leq F^{-1}_{X}(x))$.

Comment: Sorry but, **as already explained**, when $X$ is uniform on $(0,1)$, $g=F_X$ is simply $g(x)=x$ for every $x$ in $(0,1)$, hence $g(X)=X$ hence $g(X)$ is distributed like $X$ hence the distribution of $g(X)$ is... (@madprob's comment is hinting at a more general result than needed to solve the question you were asked.)

Comment: Thanks both of you, got it now! :-)