# What is the definition of $F_X(X)$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I have been reading the [Wikipedia article on the probability integral transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_integral_transform). Given a continuous random variable $X$ with cumulative distribution function $F_X$, the article defines a random variable $Y = F_X(X)$ and it shows that $Y$ has a standard uniform distribution. But by [definition of the cumulative distribution function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function#Definition), $F_X(x) = P(X \leq x),$ so shouldn't $$F_X(X) = P(X \leq X) = 1,$$ no matter what value $X$ takes? In that case, the probability integral transform theorem wouldn't hold, so I suspect that there's something I'm getting wrong about the definition of $F_X(X)$.

(*Research I've done on StackExchange prior to asking this question*: I found a similar question on [What is the meaning of $F_X(X)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2518429/what-is-the-meaning-of-f-xx). However, I could not find an answer to my question in the comments there.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In probability theory, a random variable $Z$, is a (measurable) function from the sample space $\Omega$ to the set $\mathbb{R}$ of real numbers: $\omega\mapsto Z(\omega)$.

Given any (Borel measurable) function $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, one can define the random variable $g(Z):\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ with
$$
[g(Z)](\omega):=g(Z(\omega)).
$$

For instance, if $g(x)=x^2+1$, $g(Z)(\omega)=g(Z(\omega))=[Z(\omega)]^2+1$. One can suppress the "variable" $\omega$ and write $g(Z)=Z^2+1$.

In the case of $Y:=F_X(X)$, what this really means is:
$$
Y(\omega)=F_X(X(\omega))\;\tag{1}
$$
Note in particular that $F_X:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is a function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, and for each $\omega$, $X(\omega)$ is a real number.

In this case, suppressing the variable $\omega$ may cause confusion, because the notation $P(X\le a)$ for any real number $a$ really means
$$
P(\{\omega'\in\Omega: X(\omega')\le a\})\tag{2}
$$
Thus, the right-hand side of (1), for *each* $\omega$, is
$$
F_X(X(\omega))=P(\{\omega'\in\Omega: X(\omega')\le X(\omega)\})
$$
where the real number $X(\omega)$ takes the place of $a$ in (2).

If one naively interprets $F_X(X)$ as $P(X\le X)$, one would get the wrong version of the random variable $F_X(X)=1$.

To find the distribution of $F_X(X)$:
$$
\{\omega\in \Omega: F_X(X(\omega))\le y)\}=
\{\omega\in \Omega: X(\omega)\le F_X^{-1}(y)\}\tag{3}
$$
It thus follows from (3) that
$$
P(F_X(X)\le y)=F_X(F_X^{-1}(y))=y\tag{4}
$$
In both (3) and (4), we use the assumption that $X$ is a *continuous* random variable.

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, the symbol $F_X(X)$ is confusing.

A more proper way of expressing it:

Say we have two random variables $X, X'$, which are independent and have the same distribution, i.e. $F_X = F_{X'}$. We then define $Y = F_X(X')$, namely the function $F_X$ applied to the random variable $X'$.

We may calculate the distribution function of $Y$:
\begin{eqnarray}
F_Y(y) &=& P(Y \leq y)\\
&=& P(F_X(X') \leq y)\\
&=& P(X' \leq F_X^{-1}(y))\\
&=& F_{X'}(F_X^{-1}(y))\\
&=& F_X(F_X^{-1}(y))\\
&=& y.
\end{eqnarray}

You will notice that the random variable $X'$ is kind of a dummy, which isn't very useful. In fact it doesn't really matter whether $X$ and $X'$ are independent or not, as we are only using $X$ to define its distribution function $F_X$.

Thus people tend to just write $F_X(X)$.

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, it is *not* the expression $\mathsf P(X\leq X)$ which is a confusing mess. We do not seek the probability that $X$ is at most itself, which is indeed $1$.

The composition of $F_X(X)$ is the cumulative distribution function for $X$ evaluated at the value of the random variable $X$.   It is a random variable expressing the (prior) probability that $X$ is at most whatever the value that it realises.

If that subptle distinction causes headaches: we're simply evaluating $F_X(X)$ as we would any other function $g(X)$.

So, we substitute the random variable for the argument of the CDF *after* it is evaluated.

---

$$\begin{align}F_X(X) &= \left.{\mathsf P(X\leq x)\raise{2ex}{}}\right\rvert_{x=X}\\[3ex]&=\left[(1-\mathrm e^{-\lambda x})\mathbf 1_{0\leqslant x}\right]_{x=X}&&\text{if }X\sim\mathcal{Exp}(\lambda)\\[1ex]&=(1-\mathrm e^{-\lambda X})\mathbf 1_{0\leqslant X}\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

The formula $F_X(t) = \Pr[X \le t]$ tells us how the function $F_X$ is related to the distribution of the random variable $X$, but that's all: $F_X$ is just a function. In many cases you can write down what that function is: for example, if $X \sim \text{Exp}(\lambda)$, then $$F_X(t) = \begin{cases} 1 - e^{-\lambda t} & t \ge 0 \\ 0 & t < 0\end{cases}$$
The random variable $F_X(X)$ is defined by evaluating *that function* at $X$: not the probability expression we used to define the function, but the function itself. Given a real number, $F_X$ outputs a probability: the real number we give it is the value of $X$.

Continuing the example of $X \sim \text{Exp}(\lambda)$, $F_X(X)$ would be the random variable equal to $1 - e^{-\lambda X}$. (The second case of the definition doesn't matter here, because $X$ is never negative.)